# A recursive sequence for prime numbers invented!

Tags: prime-numbers

I invented a recursive sequence below nearly 10 years ago, which assigns unity to every non-prime number and also gives all prime numbers. Do you think it is useful?!

Starting with  $a_0=2$, we have:

$$a_{m+1}=2\prod_{i=0}^m(3+i)a_{m-i}^{-\sum_{k=1}^{3+m}\left\lfloor(3+m)a_{m-i}^{-k}\right\rfloor}$$

As pointed out by @MattiP., We indeed get:

$$2, 3, 1, 5, 1, 7, 1, 1, 1, 11, 1, 13, 1, 1, 1, 17,…$$

**NOTE:** There is a virtue about this recursive formula because, using a proper computer program, we can simplify the numerator and denominator of the produced fractions (for great values of $m$) before dividing/multiplying them by each other.

**UPDATE:** I also found the following recursive sequence in my old article. However, can anybody please verify its correctness using a computer program?!

$$a_{m+1}=\frac{m^2}{2}+\frac{7m}{2}+6-\sum_{i_m=0}^{(m+3)\operatorname{sgn}(a_m)}\space ... \space \sum_{i_1=0}^{(m+3)\operatorname{sgn}(a_1)}\space\sum_{i_0=0}^{(m+3)\operatorname{sgn}(a_0)}\left ( f(a_k,i_k,m)\operatorname{sgn}\left (\left\lfloor{\frac{m+3}{f(a_k,i_k,m)}}\right\rfloor\right )\right )$$

where

$$f(a_k,i_k,m)=\prod_{k=0}^{m}\left ( a_k+1-\operatorname{sgn}(a_k)\right )^{i_k}$$
The number of "sums" depends on $m$. Starting with $a_0=2$, it turns out that the sequence yields:

$$2, 3, 0, 5, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 13, 0, 0, 0, 17,…$$

Comment: Do you have a proof? What inspired you to find this? Thanks.

Comment: @BenjaminWang The proof is not very similar to what we see in, say, ordinary mathematics articles. It is an "invitation" rather than a "discovery"!

Comment: @MohammadJavanshiry You mean "invention" not "invitation" in the above comment?

Comment: @DávidLaczkó Oh, yes, sorry. It was a typo.

Comment: Out of interest, I started to calculate the next number. For $m=-1$ (a bit odd but okay), we have $a_0 = 2$. Then for $m=0$, we have the expression for $a_1$ involving the following expression in the exponent:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^3 \lfloor 3 \cdot a_0^k \rfloor = \lfloor \frac{3}{2} \rfloor +  \lfloor \frac{3}{2^2} \rfloor +  \lfloor \frac{3}{2^3} \rfloor = 1 + 0 + 0 = 1
$$
so the required exponent is $-1$. Is this what you mean by the equation? If we insert this to the expression, we get
$$
a_1 = 2 (3+0) a_0 ^{-1} = \frac{2 \cdot 3}{2} = 3
$$

Comment: I guess you have to change some indices in the equation then. Perhaps you mean $a_m$ instead of $a_{m+1}$ on the LHS?

Comment: @MattiP. Seems your calculations are correct, though I do not understand why I have to amend the LHS.

Comment: After the initial term $a_0 = 2$, we want to calculate $a_1$, right? So if you have a formula to calculate $a_{m+1}$ then that means that, in order to calculate $a_1$, we have to have $m=0$.

Comment: I calculated a few terms and I get the sequence
$$
2,~3,~1,~5,~1,~7,~1,~1,~1,~11,~1,~13,~1,~1,~1,~17, \ldots
$$
Does it seem like correct?

Comment: It seems like, if you ignore all the 1's, it indeed lists all prime numbers. But then again, when the numbers gets larger, it becomes increasingly more expensive to calculate the next number.

Comment: @MattiP. Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Note: https://oeis.org/A089026

Comment: @MattiP. Does this link use the same formula as mine?

Comment: As you see, there are several formulas listed for the sequence. But I don't know what else to comment about your specific approach. Just that, computationally, it can be a bit tricky due to rounding errors. It's easy to bump into situations involving $0^0 $ ...

Comment: To have at least a bit evidence that this formula is actually correct , it should be calculated far further , say , the first $10^7$ terms. Next, we should determine the effort needed to find , say , a $20$-digit prime. If this takes almost an eternity , the sequence is of little practical use , theoretically, it can still have some merit.

Comment: You should still prove / justify / explain this formula more!

Comment: It takes value of prime number if input is a prime else it takes $1$ for composite numbers right @Mohammad Javanshiry?

Comment: @Rahul It takes the value of a prime number if the input of $m+2$ is a prime, otherwise it takes 1.

Comment: What is the question though? If whether we think it is useful, that is matter of opinion ...